# Test coverage for if statement with logical or (||) - with Java's short circuiting, what's the forth condition JaCoCo wants me to cover?

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco, short-circuiting, test-coverage

This is probably a rather simple question, but I'm at a loss...

I have an if statement like the following:

```
if(TheEnum.A.equals(myEnum) || TheEnum.B.equals(myEnum))
```

`TheEnum` can be `A`, `B`, `C`, ... `G` (more than just 4 options).

JaCoCo (SONAR) tells me that there are four conditions I can cover here.
Which ones are those?
Isn't the entire set I can test for in this instance essentially

```
if(true || not_evaluated) => true
if(false || true) => true
if(false || false) => false
```

I'm pretty sure I can't specifically test for
`if(true || true)` or
`if(true || false)`,
as short circuit evaluation won't get that far...?

If so, what is the forth option JaCoCo/Sonar wants me to test for?

Comment: Try the non-shortcircuiting `|` to see what JaCoCo says to that.

Comment: I find this very puzzling behavior.   To me it's actually not that short-circuit won't let you test both (true, true) and (true, false) cases - it's that the case (true, true) `cannot` exist.  If myEnum is A, it is `not` B.   I can only see three cases in the given snippet of code.  `myEnum` must be one of (A, B, not-A-or-B).   That's three cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right, this code is short-circuiting. It's compiled into bytecode roughly like this (assuming Java has goto):

```
if(TheEnum.A.equals(myEnum)) goto ok;
if(!TheEnum.B.equals(myEnum)) goto end;
ok:
   // body of if statement
end:
```

So as JaCoCo analyzes the bytecode, from its point of view you have the two independent checks: first `if` and second `if`, which generate four possible branches. You may consider this as a JaCoCo bug, but I guess it's not very easy to fix this robustly and it is not very disturbing, so you can live with it.

Comment: Well, it reduces coverage. And with a 95% target and a few of these in a short class, it kind of does matter... ;)

Comment: @Christian time to explain your manager that high coverage does not mean high quality, then ;)

Comment: @Christian: there are many cases when you cannot get 100% coverage. For example, asserts inside methods. Or `catch(CloneNotSupportedException ex)` in `clone()` method. On the other hand 100% coverage is not a silver bullet. History knows many cool bugs which were unnoticed despite the 100% coverage. E. g. calculating an average with `(a+b)/2`. It's simply to cover it, it has no branches, but if you don't test it on numbers higher than `Integer.MAX_VALUE/2` you won't notice a bug.

Answer (score 1):

If the 100% score matters more than anything else...
... use this approach:

```
if (Boolean.logicalOr(TheEnum.A.equals(myEnum), TheEnum.B.equals(myEnum))) {
    ...
```

Or use the binary or

```
if (TheEnum.A.equals(myEnum) | TheEnum.B.equals(myEnum)) {
    ...
```

You may nest the calls as deep as you like, or use an own `or` function:

```
if (or(TheEnum.A.equals(myEnum), TheEnum.B.equals(myEnum))) {
    ...

public static boolean or(Boolean... vals) {
    for (Boolean v : vals) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(v))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using a standalone testable function `or` will test 100% of it.

Note that this may affect the performance... I told you!
Also hiding all these decisions may backfire!