# Test for: ArrayList is null AND size is zero

Tags: java, arraylist, jacoco

I have the following code

```
static final Criteria<TheGetMessage> NO_EVENTS =
            message -> (message.getTypes() != null) && (message.getTypes().size() == 0);
```

and SonarQube says that 3/4 branches covered for it. It is illogical, that one of the cases is: ArrayList object is null AND ArrayList object size method being called. Because lazy evaluation will not check second condition. **message** class doesn't contain unchecked conditions. 
Any help will be great!

Comment: If you care about Sonar so much, why not write it in a more explicit way, using two ifs inside one another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test coverage for if statement with logical or (||) - with Java's short circuiting, what's the forth condition JaCoCo wants me to cover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31546047/test-coverage-for-if-statement-with-logical-or-with-javas-short-circuiti)

Comment: This has nothing to do with SonarQube but rather with your tool coverage that I assume is JaCoCo. Don't shoot the messenger :)